# How to use modern string formatting options with Python's logging module?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

The [Python logging tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-variable-data) says that the newer ways of formatting are beyond the scope of the tutorial, without mentioning where to learn about it.

I would appreciate any examples or link to documentation that allow me to use `.format()` style message formatting in logging calls such as `debug()`, `info()`, etc.

Comment: The question and answer are out-of-date and link to Python 2 documentation.  The most modern string-formatting approach (f-strings since Python 3.6) work nicely with logging calls, e.g. `logging.debug(f'var = {var}')`. The [latest documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#formatting-styles) covers the approach with `BraceMessage`.

Comment: Note also that pylint can be configured to achieve consistency in logging. If you use f-strings, as suggested e.g. by `pzelnip` at [f-strings advantages for logging; performance](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2354#issuecomment-414526879), then in `.pylintrc` you might want `disable=logging-fstring-interpolation,`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recently, I was looking for that too. I think I got pointed to the solution here on SO, but I only have the final url at hand. This is what I do:

```
# http://plumberjack.blogspot.de/2010/10/supporting-alternative-formatting.html
class BraceMessage(object):
    def __init__(self, fmt, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fmt = fmt
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fmt.format(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

_F = BraceMessage
```

Can be used like this:

```
logger.debug(_F("foo {0} {quux}", bar, quux=baz))
```

The formatting will only take place in the very moment the message is evaluated, so you don't lose lots of performance if a log level is disabled. The author of that snippet above made this (and some other utilities) available as a package: [`logutils`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/logutils/).

Comment: Why not just call it `F` or `L`? Don't need to use two characters when one is sufficient. The leading underscore is supposed to indicate a private attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to enable using `format` style in python 3.2+

```
import logging

class BracketStyleRecord(logging.LogRecord):
    def getMessage(self):
        msg = str(self.msg) # see logging cookbook
        if self.args:
            try:
                msg = msg % self.args # retro-compability for 3rd party code
            except TypeError: # not all arguments converted during formatting
                msg = msg.format(*self.args)
        return msg

logging.setLogRecordFactory(BracketStyleRecord)
logging.basicConfig()
logging.error("The first number is %s", 1) # old-style
logging.error("The first number is {}", 1) # new-style
```

For details, caveats and references see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715402/1595865).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to logging format Pylint can also be named as a source.
See [Pylint logging-format-interpolation W1202](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/logging-format-interpolation.html).

- `%s` formatting is preferred over `"{}".format("foo")`
- f-string is also reasonable (adaption of Pylint config needed)